# Notification on creation of term

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is it possible to get notification once a term is getting created using Enterprise Metadata and Keywords Settings feature of a list?

Comment: Is that information make sense to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot create an alert or notification on creating term within Enterprise Metadata & Keywords settings.

There are also few limitations mentioned in below link that can help you to understand the Metadata limitations.

[Managed Metadata Column Limitations](http://blog.bonzai-intranet.com/analysthq/2011/06/managed-metadata-column-limitations/)

Comment: If you find the information helpful than please make it as appropriate answer so others can get benefit of it... :)

Comment: Upvote it for the sake of my reputation... :)

Comment: Sure :)...it is helpful :)